# Transperency Gets Lost while Converting Image through Image Magick

Tags: java, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to upload an image for a product in Different resolution. The image has an transparent background.

While converting in larger resolution transparency remains exist while converting it in Image resolution 515Wx515H and lower then transparency getting lost.

Can any one suggest me regarding this if faced the same issue before.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552144/resize-image-in-java-without-losing-transparency look into this

Comment: Please show use the code/command your using. It's more than possible that the destination format doesn't support transparencies, or that a colorspace/matte operation removes it.

Comment: It may be possible the images may be getting saved as JPEG which won't preserve transparency in original image. Were you able to sort this out? Generally for such cases, you first identify type of image, and separate logic  for image formats which supports transparency to work correctly in your image processing pipeline.

Comment: Yeah the JPEG only supports transparent. the image I converted is PNG which does not support the transparency. So I went with JPEG